# Android ADK - Connect multiple devices

Tags: android, adk, accessory

Is it possible, to connect more than one accessory to my device using the ADK? For example using a nexus and a usb hub. Could I connect two arduino boards?

Comment: I think this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, but the APIs do allow for this feature to be supported whenever the underlying system can.